# Create a log of all keyboard key pressed during a day in android

Tags: android, android-service, keylistener, android-logcat, android-keypad

I am new in android and want to create a log file of all key strokes pressed on keyboard in an android device. My app will display all the key pressed in a log file containing the key value and exact keyboard value of any type of keyboard user uses. As I know we can run our app in background using services and broadcastreciver concept, but i want to trap all the key strokes values to be stored in the log file from any other app or phone operation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is to create an keyboard app first. In that app, you can do anything you want. Right now, I don't think it is possible to hook in native keyboard app to get keys pressed.

Comment: I read about softkey keyboard that is integrated to do keyevents for keyboard in our app, but i want to try outside my app too for everykey strokes. or i have researched about the motion sensors that uses in games but i am trying to do that using general app.

Comment: If you develop a keyborad app, set it as default keyboard. With this, it would be your app which would be handling key stroke events. With this, you can log whatever you want to log.