# Get Keyboard key press in Background Android Application

Tags: java, android, background-process, keyboard-events

I need to create a Android application to get all pressed numbers and letters. This application needs be in background/minimized.

Comment: We need to see what you have done so-far, please add some code.

Comment: I do not know where to start. I'm reading about background application and BroadcastReceiver...but I'm a little confuse yet.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think this is possible with native keyboard,But still you can check below question,you might get an idea.
[KeyLogger How to create in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629145/create-a-log-of-all-keyboard-key-pressed-during-a-day-in-android)